# Tag merge and alias request: [zend-framework3] and [zf3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

There are two different tags exists on Stack Overflow for the new [Zend Framework 3](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-06-28-zend-framework-3.html) version:

- [zf3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zf3) - 67 questions
- [zend-framework3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework3) - 112 questions

IMHO, since the previous version has a well-known [zend-framework2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework2) tag with a [zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zf2) alias, [zf3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zf3) should also be an alias for [zend-framework3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework3) and Zend Framework 3 related questions should be merged under [zend-framework3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework3) tag.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be [tag:zend-framework-3]?

Comment: I think so too. However Zend Framework 2 tagged as `zend-framework2` in the past and `zf2` is an alias for the `zend-framework2`. IMHO same convention should be applied for the zend-framework3 for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Can both `2` and `3` be updated?